# N-Network Wifi Disconnect Debian 9

Tags: wireless-networking, debian, home-networking

I have Debian 9 installed on a laptop that I keep at home. The laptop connects to the internet using wifi. My router has two networks, a 2.4 GHz and a 5 GHz. The 2.4 is G and the 5 is N/AC. There is significant interferance for the 2.4 network so I try and use the 5 most of the time.

Usually the laptop connects to the N network without issue. However, every few days it looses connection and cannot get it back. I can see the network and have signal but when I try and connect it just fails after some time. Rebooting the laptop doesn't help and neither does rebooting the router. Eventually it is able to connect without issue but I can't figure out why. It never has any issue connecting to the G network.

I have the following output from `dmesg`:

```
[   57.441657] wlp4s0: associate with 10:da:43:bc:24:13 (try 1/3)
[   57.442522] wlp4s0: RX AssocResp from 10:da:43:bc:24:13 (capab=0x1011 status=0 aid=3)
[   57.460626] wlp4s0: associated
[   60.253674] wlp4s0: deauthenticating from 10:da:43:bc:24:13 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[   60.326542] wlp4s0: authenticate with 10:da:43:bc:24:13
[   60.329673] wlp4s0: send auth to 10:da:43:bc:24:13 (try 1/3)
[   60.410949] wlp4s0: authenticated
[   60.413799] wlp4s0: associate with 10:da:43:bc:24:13 (try 1/3)
[   60.414725] wlp4s0: RX AssocResp from 10:da:43:bc:24:13 (capab=0x1011 status=0 aid=3)
[   60.433036] wlp4s0: associated
[   70.438856] wlp4s0: deauthenticating from 10:da:43:bc:24:13 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[   81.307914] wlp4s0: authenticate with 10:da:43:bc:24:13
[   81.311042] wlp4s0: send auth to 10:da:43:bc:24:13 (try 1/3)
[   81.402982] wlp4s0: authenticated
[   81.405972] wlp4s0: associate with 10:da:43:bc:24:13 (try 1/3)
[   81.406754] wlp4s0: RX AssocResp from 10:da:43:bc:24:13 (capab=0x1011 status=0 aid=3)
[   81.424622] wlp4s0: associated
[   85.258093] wlp4s0: deauthenticating from 10:da:43:bc:24:13 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[   85.307476] wlp4s0: authenticate with 10:da:43:bc:24:13
[   85.310608] wlp4s0: send auth to 10:da:43:bc:24:13 (try 1/3)
[   85.396766] wlp4s0: authenticated
[   85.397924] wlp4s0: associate with 10:da:43:bc:24:13 (try 1/3)
[   85.398815] wlp4s0: RX AssocResp from 10:da:43:bc:24:13 (capab=0x1011 status=0 aid=3)
[   85.416923] wlp4s0: associated
[   95.417941] wlp4s0: deauthenticating from 10:da:43:bc:24:13 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  106.506127] wlp4s0: authenticate with 10:da:43:bc:24:13
[  106.510613] wlp4s0: send auth to 10:da:43:bc:24:13 (try 1/3)
[  106.593598] wlp4s0: authenticated
[  106.594489] wlp4s0: associate with 10:da:43:bc:24:13 (try 1/3)
[  106.595251] wlp4s0: RX AssocResp from 10:da:43:bc:24:13 (capab=0x1011 status=0 aid=3)
[  106.613155] wlp4s0: associated
[  108.332268] wlp4s0: deauthenticating from 10:da:43:bc:24:13 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
```

And looking in the system logs I see this:

```
Jan 22 06:52:10 debian-tv wpa_supplicant[570]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="my_wifi_network"
Jan 22 06:52:10 debian-tv wpa_supplicant[570]: wlp4s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 10:da:43:bc:24:13 (SSID='my_wifi_network' freq=5560 MHz)
Jan 22 06:52:10 debian-tv kernel: [213853.432382] wlp4s0: authenticate with 10:da:43:bc:24:13
Jan 22 06:52:10 debian-tv kernel: [213853.434847] wlp4s0: send auth to 10:da:43:bc:24:13 (try 1/3)
Jan 22 06:52:10 debian-tv NetworkManager[446]: <info>  [1516621930.1687] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jan 22 06:52:10 debian-tv wpa_supplicant[570]: wlp4s0: Trying to associate with 10:da:43:bc:24:13 (SSID='my_wifi_network' freq=5560 MHz)
Jan 22 06:52:10 debian-tv kernel: [213853.488669] wlp4s0: authenticated
Jan 22 06:52:10 debian-tv kernel: [213853.492272] wlp4s0: associate with 10:da:43:bc:24:13 (try 1/3)
Jan 22 06:52:10 debian-tv kernel: [213853.493062] wlp4s0: RX AssocResp from 10:da:43:bc:24:13 (capab=0x1011 status=0 aid=3)
Jan 22 06:52:10 debian-tv NetworkManager[446]: <info>  [1516621930.2293] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jan 22 06:52:10 debian-tv wpa_supplicant[570]: wlp4s0: Associated with 10:da:43:bc:24:13
Jan 22 06:52:10 debian-tv kernel: [213853.510954] wlp4s0: associated
Jan 22 06:52:10 debian-tv NetworkManager[446]: <info>  [1516621930.2500] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Jan 22 06:52:14 debian-tv NetworkManager[446]: <warn>  [1516621934.3489] device (wlp4s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
Jan 22 06:52:14 debian-tv NetworkManager[446]: <info>  [1516621934.3490] device (wlp4s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Jan 22 06:52:14 debian-tv kernel: [213857.618638] wlp4s0: deauthenticating from 10:da:43:bc:24:13 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Jan 22 06:52:14 debian-tv NetworkManager[446]: <warn>  [1516621934.3545] device (wlp4s0): Activation: (wifi) asking for new secrets
Jan 22 06:52:14 debian-tv wpa_supplicant[570]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=10:da:43:bc:24:13 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Jan 22 06:52:14 debian-tv wpa_supplicant[570]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Jan 22 06:52:14 debian-tv NetworkManager[446]: <warn>  [1516621934.3843] sup-iface[0x562c700c6830,wlp4s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Jan 22 06:52:14 debian-tv NetworkManager[446]: <info>  [1516621934.3844] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
Jan 22 06:52:14 debian-tv NetworkManager[446]: <info>  [1516621934.3895] device (wlp4s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Jan 22 06:52:14 debian-tv NetworkManager[446]: <info>  [1516621934.4103] device (wlp4s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jan 22 06:52:14 debian-tv NetworkManager[446]: <info>  [1516621934.4106] device (wlp4s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'my_wifi_network' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Jan 22 06:52:14 debian-tv NetworkManager[446]: <info>  [1516621934.4106] Config: added 'ssid' value 'my_wifi_network'
Jan 22 06:52:14 debian-tv NetworkManager[446]: <info>  [1516621934.4106] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jan 22 06:52:14 debian-tv NetworkManager[446]: <info>  [1516621934.4107] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Jan 22 06:52:14 debian-tv NetworkManager[446]: <info>  [1516621934.4107] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Jan 22 06:52:14 debian-tv NetworkManager[446]: <info>  [1516621934.4107] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Jan 22 06:52:14 debian-tv wpa_supplicant[570]: wlp4s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 10:da:43:bc:24:13 (SSID='my_wifi_network' freq=5560 MHz)
Jan 22 06:52:14 debian-tv kernel: [213857.697118] wlp4s0: authenticate with 10:da:43:bc:24:13
Jan 22 06:52:14 debian-tv NetworkManager[446]: <info>  [1516621934.4337] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
Jan 22 06:52:14 debian-tv kernel: [213857.700842] wlp4s0: send auth to 10:da:43:bc:24:13 (try 1/3)
Jan 22 06:52:14 debian-tv wpa_supplicant[570]: wlp4s0: Trying to associate with 10:da:43:bc:24:13 (SSID='my_wifi_network' freq=5560 MHz)
Jan 22 06:52:14 debian-tv kernel: [213857.789529] wlp4s0: authenticated
Jan 22 06:52:14 debian-tv kernel: [213857.792103] wlp4s0: associate with 10:da:43:bc:24:13 (try 1/3)
Jan 22 06:52:14 debian-tv kernel: [213857.793018] wlp4s0: RX AssocResp from 10:da:43:bc:24:13 (capab=0x1011 status=0 aid=3)
Jan 22 06:52:14 debian-tv NetworkManager[446]: <info>  [1516621934.5275] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jan 22 06:52:14 debian-tv wpa_supplicant[570]: wlp4s0: Associated with 10:da:43:bc:24:13
Jan 22 06:52:14 debian-tv kernel: [213857.812804] wlp4s0: associated
Jan 22 06:52:14 debian-tv NetworkManager[446]: <info>  [1516621934.5508] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Jan 22 06:52:24 debian-tv wpa_supplicant[570]: wlp4s0: Authentication with 10:da:43:bc:24:13 timed out.
Jan 22 06:52:24 debian-tv kernel: [213867.814182] wlp4s0: deauthenticating from 10:da:43:bc:24:13 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Jan 22 06:52:24 debian-tv wpa_supplicant[570]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=10:da:43:bc:24:13 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Jan 22 06:52:24 debian-tv wpa_supplicant[570]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="my_wifi_network" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
```

So it looks like it can't authenticate but I'm not sure why. Can anyone help me out? If you need more info let me know and I can get it.

I'm running Debian 9 stable and have the latest packages as well as the non-free firmware for my wifi card.